# SharePoint - get value of calculated field without manual parsing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a calculated field in a list with this formula:
`=CID & " - " & Title`

When viewing the list, it might display as: "2 - Big Meeting".  When I grab the value from code like so:
`myItem["CIDandTitle"]`

the value comes back as: "string;#2 - BigMeeting".  Is there a "correct" way in sharepoint to extract the value or should i simply split on the semicolon and pound sign?

I am using MOSS2007.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to cast it to an SPCalculatedField:

```
SPFieldCalculated cf = (SPFieldCalculated)myItem.Fields["CIDandTitle"];
string value = cf.GetFieldValueForEdit(myItem["CIDandTitle"]);
```

or

```
string value = cf.GetFieldValueAsText(myItem["CIDandTitle"]);
```

Comment: That works; as does cf.GetFieldValueAsText(myItem["CIDandTitle"]).  This approach seems clunky though.

Comment: I had issues trying to get a float this way.  I used myItem.GetFormattedValue("floatValue");

Comment: I resorted to `myItem.GetFormattedValue("floatValue")` as @bryanbcook suggests because the `.Fields` accessor expects the display name and not the robust internal name.
GetFormattedValue does work with internal name!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Nathan does not specify that you need to provide the display name of the field. It wont work with internalName. Moreover, I'm likely to use *as* to cast the result.

```
var cf = list.Fields["calculatedfieldDisplayName"] as  SPFieldCalculated;
String value = cf.GetFieldValueAsText(item["calculatedfieldDisplayName"]);
```