# SharePoint 2010: field formulas

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know a way using either the SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model or the SharePoint 2010 web services to evaluate the formula for a given field?  For example, if I have a DateTime column whose default value is set to a formula like:

```
=DATEDIF([Column1], [Column2],"d")
```

or

```
=MONTH([TODAY])
```

I would like to be able to somehow evaluate this formula from a client application.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

**EDIT:**

I am dealing specifically with DateTime calculated default values which seem to be handled differently than a typical "calculated" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no client side way to evaluate such formula by itself using SharePoint APIs and I don't think server side API is publically available.

Your best option is to update an item and read the field back.

Comment: These are great answers, but unfortunately, I do not have a list item when I am attempting to evaluate the formula.

Answer (score 3):

If you just get the value for that field it'll evaluate. The formula itself is stored in the field definition for the list.

So just getting `MyListItem["MyCalculatedColumn"]` will evaluate the formula.

Comment: These are great answers, but unfortunately, I do not have a list item when I am attempting to evaluate the formula.

Comment: In that case, from code, you could maybe use SPListItemCollection.Add(), get the value, but do not do an Update(), and the item won't be written.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer on [StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898291/sharepoint-get-value-of-calculated-field-without-manual-parsing).

The part of the object model you need is [SPFieldCalculated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcalculated.getfieldvalueastext.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Nat, but these are DateTime columns specifically, I should have said that in the text rather than just stating it as an example.  I have edited to show this.

Comment: Does the SPFieldCalculated.OutputType=SPFieldType.DateTime Property not help?