# Sharepoint 2010 dates and calculated fields

Tags: sharepoint-2010

For reasons I don't pretend to understand calculated fields that are set to return a date return the value in code in this format:

"datetime;#2015-04-25 00:00:00"

so dim myDate as datetime = oMasterItem("Contract End Date") fails, and you can't cast the value either.

How do I convert that to a real date format without doing string manipulation ?

(or am I missing something obvious?)

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how and where you got "datetime;#2015-04-25 00:00:00"? Was this done programmatically or what? Please provide a more detailed explanation on your current scenario.

Comment: its a calculated field that returns a date value based on a date + 12 months (which does result in a valid date)

Comment: apparently this is the only way you can do it due to the way calculated fields return their value

Convert.ToDateTime(oMasterItem("Contract End Date").ToString().Substring(10))

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
[SharePoint - get value of calculated field without manual parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898291/sharepoint-get-value-of-calculated-field-without-manual-parsing)

You can do it by:

```
SPFieldCalculated cf = (SPFieldCalculated)myItem.Fields["CIDandTitle"];
string value = cf.GetFieldValueForEdit(myItem["CIDandTitle"]);
```

or

```
string value = cf.GetFieldValueAsText(myItem["CIDandTitle"]);
```